# How can I use role GUIDs instead of names in ASP.NET Core Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I've been playing around with Identity in ASP.NET Core using a few samples and something is frustrating me. Even though the role model has a primary key `Id` and a string `Name`, it's the name that gets passed around by the various built-in services.

For example, when I call `_userManager.GetRolesAsync(user)` I get back a list of string names. What if I want the IDs? There's no API for this so I'd have to use a role manager to get all roles and map them. By default role names are not constrained with a unique key so this isn't reliable.

I must be missing something, but what? My use case right now is that I want to populate a JWT claim with a user's roles. As far as I'm concerned the role names are internal to my application and I don't want to expose these to clients.

Comment: `What if I want the IDs?` What does this mean? You want to get user role id? Just like `_dbContext.Roles.Single(x => x.Name == "Administrator")`?

Comment: I thought my question was clear, sorry. I want to reference roles by their `Id` property (which in my case is a stringified GUID), not their `Name` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `_userManager.GetRolesAsync(user)`, it calls `userRoleStore.GetRolesAsync`

```
        public virtual async Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(TUser user)
    {
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        var userRoleStore = GetUserRoleStore();
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
        }
        return await userRoleStore.GetRolesAsync(user, CancellationToken);
    }
```

For returning role id instead of role names, you could custom `userRoleStore.GetRolesAsync` by implement your own `UserStore`.

- UserStore.cs

  ```
             public class CustomUserStore : UserStore<IdentityUser>
  {
      public CustomUserStore(DbContext context, IdentityErrorDescriber describer = null) : base(context, describer)
      {
      }

      public override async Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(IdentityUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
      {
          var roleNames = await base.GetRolesAsync(user, cancellationToken);
          var roleIds = await Context.Set<IdentityRole>()
                               .Where(r => roleNames.Contains(r.Name))
                               .Select(r => r.Id)
                               .ToListAsync();

          return roleIds;
      }
  }
  ```
- Register UserStore

  ```
      services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
          .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
          .AddUserStore<CustomUserStore>()
          .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
          ;
      services.AddScoped<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>();
  ```
- Then you will get role id collection by

  ```
      var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);
      var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
  ```